# Can't launch JBoss7 from Eclipse Indigo

Tags: jboss7.x, eclipse-indigo, jboss-tools

I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I have Eclipse Indigo, JBoss 7.1, JBoss Tools installed. I have this configuration working on my Windows7 64-bit system. I am attempting to set up a co-worker's Windows XP 32-bit machine with the same configuration but am not able to get the server to launch. I have configured the server but when I attempt to start the server, I get an error indicating that it was unable to start the server but there is no specific error listed.

- I am able to start JBoss from the command prompt using the standalone.bat file.
- I am able to configure the standalone.xml file from within Eclipse. I have confirmed this by checking the file in the standalone/configuration directory.
- When I attempt to publish the project from within Eclipse, it does not publish.
- Nothing gets written to server.log
- The startup parameters match what I have on my computer.

I can't figure out what I am missing. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Edit:
I have done some more checking. I am able to publish to the server and I am able to start the server (with the published application) fine from the command prompt. That part works. When I attempt to start the server from within Eclipse it gives me "Server JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server failed to start." It never writes anything to the console tab in Eclipse either so I can't tell why it is failing to start.

Also in the Servers tab, there is an entry called "Server Details". When I expand that entry, it says "Not Connected".

Comment: how about checking the versions , you are on 64-bit he is on 32-bit , AFAIK , jdk as well as jb distros will differ for both architectures

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I go to the JBoss site, there is only one download for JBossAS7 so I assumed it didn't matter which platform you were on as long as you had the right jdk installed. I can check the jdk again but I would assume that if he had the wrong one on his computer then JBoss wouldn't have started from the command prompt either.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AS710FinalReleaseNotes may be this will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my problem is that Eclipse had be configured to use the java JDK, not the JRE. As soon as I switched over to use the JDK it started working fine. For some reason JBoss will start under 64-bit windows with the JRE but under 32-bit you need to use the JDK. I found the answer here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/169097